# How to map Result<'a,'b> to Reader<Result<'a,'b> in f#?

Tags: f#, reader-monad

I have the function to map a function to "Reader-Result", where f is `'a->'b:
('a->'b) -> Reader<Result<'a,'c>> -> Reader<Result<'b,'c>>`

```
let map f = Reader.map <| Result.map f
```

But how to I write a similar map that takes the function `'a->Result<'b,'c>` as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that's analogous to `map`, but whose argument returns a `Result<_,_>`, is called `bind`. Its signature is:

```
bind : ('a -> Result<'b, 'c>) -> Result<'a, 'c> -> Result<'b, 'c>
```

I am assuming that the signature you want is:

```
yourFunction : ('a -> Result<'b, 'c>) -> Reader<Result<'a, 'c>> -> Reader<Result<'b, 'c>>
```

To obtain such function, combine `Result.bind` with `Reader.map`:

```
yourFunction f = Reader.map <| Result.bind f
```

Comment: Of course, obvious when i see it! Just what i was looking for, thanks!